# Facebook Comment Like count

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like, comments, facebook-javascript-sdk

i testing the webpage where i want to pull current users comment like count on my webpage.

I tested so many code but anything is not working for me.

Can anyone show me how to pull the like count for current users comment.

I tried Javascript, php sdk but could not pull the information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to having a unique ID for each comment, you should have a common ID that references the page/topic they are on. Its then very easy to do a SQL select where page ID is that particular page and get the count.